# Login with no facebook account with FBSDKLoginBehaviorWeb appear a blank page

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I am try to login in Facebook `webview` in my app (`FBSDKLoginBehaviorWeb`)

[image: FBSDKLoginBehaviorWeb]

But if I try a No Facebook account (eg. `email: notregistered@noemail.com` `password: 123456`) it appear a `blank page`. I expect it return some `error`.

[image: Blank Page]

Here my code.

```
FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
login.loginBehavior = FBSDKLoginBehaviorWeb;

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
   [login logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"public_profile"] 
                           handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
   }}];
```

It important to say that the `handler` do not be execute and is not possible to access the result and `error`.

What should I do to avoid the `blank page` or get some `API error`?

Comment: yes, Same problem as you, if I am login with another user its working fine.

Comment: Please file a bug at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs.

Comment: A bug was open at facebook: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/732034976906199 after it close the bug not reproduce again.